# Arreglo variable en Java

Tags: java, array

necesito hacer que la longitud del arreglo sea declarada por el usuario que corre el programa y que no este establecida dentro del código, esto es lo que llevo pero ya me confundí y no se que hacer apenas estoy aprendiendo a programar.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/* */
class UN {

private double Calificacion[];
private int j;
private int x[];

public UN() {

    Calificacion = new double[];
}

public void setCalificacion() {

    System.out.println(" Introduce las calificaciones ");
    Scanner dato = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int j = 0; j < Calificacion.length; j++) {
        Calificacion[j] = dato.nextDouble();
    }

}

public double getCalificacion() {
    for (int j = 0; j < Calificacion.length; j++) {
        System.out.println(Calificacion[j]);

    }
    return Calificacion[j];
}

}

public class MensajeDeArreglos {

public int x;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(" Establece la longitud del arreglo ");
    Scanner dato = new Scanner(System.in);


    UN uno = new UN();
    double Calificacion[];
    Calificacion = new double[];
    System.out.println(" la longitud del arreglo es " + Calificacion.length);
    uno.setCalificacion();
    System.out.println(" Las calificaciones establecidas son: ");
    uno.getCalificacion();

}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

En este caso solo es necesario que pongas el código de las declaraciones y el método `setCalificacion`.

Para tu pregunta, prueba lo siguiente:

```
public UN() {

    double[] Calificacion;
    //variable del tamaño del array
    int icant;
}

public void setCalificacion() {

    System.out.println(" Introduce las cantidad de calificaciones");
    Scanner cant = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Conversión de scanner a int
    icant = cant.nextInt();
    //Declaración del array con el tamaño definido por el usuario
    Calificacion = new double[icant];
    System.out.println(" Introduce las calificaciones ");
    Scanner dato = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int j = 0; j < Calificacion.length; j++) {
        Calificacion[j] = dato.nextDouble();
    }

}
```